# Как достучаться к data у Response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, запрос, fetch

Я делаю запрос на определенный погодный api, *этот код обернут в асинхронную функцию, с ключевым словом async* пример:

```
const res = await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name}&appid={API key}")
if(res.ok) {
  console.log(res.data)
}
```

Но у меня не выходит достучаться до data у Response. Что делать в такой ситуации?

(city name и api key в реальном коде присутствуют)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response Где тут написано что у Response есть data?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, но ведь при запросе, обратно мы получаем объект Respone с полем body из которого я и хочу получить пришедшую data

Comment: Чего чего?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить доступ к data у Response, сначала ответ нужно спарсить в нужный формат res.json() или res.text() эти 2 метода возвращают промис, поэтому мы должны использовать await.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам будет легче сориентироваться в цепочке then

```
fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city 
name}&appid={API key}")
.then(res => {
   if(res.ok) => res.json()
 })
.then(res => console.log(res.data))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к data вы можете получить используя например метод .json() так:

```
fetch('https://...')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Или так:

```
async function foo() {
  const res = await fetch('https://...')
  const data = await res.json()
  console.log(data)
}
```